# Exportar dados para planilha excel formatando a célula

Tags: excel-vba

Estou exportando dados para o Excel, porém o formato da planilha criada não é o desejado.
Estou exportando o texto 000 porém o Excel entende como sendo número, e o valor exportado é 0.
O código que estou usando é o seguinte:
txt_exportar="000"
.range(a1).value=txt_exportar.

Outro exemplo:
txt_exportar="060"
.range(a1).value=txt_exportar.

O valor exportado para o Excel é 60.

Desde já agradeço a atenção.

Answer (score 0):

Encontrei a solução.
Basta acrescentar a seguinte linha:

Range("A1").NumberFormat = "@"